# SharePoint 2013 Convert Evaluation/Trial Version to Productive Version

Tags: 2013, evaluation

It is possible to convert a SharePoint 2013 Evaluation (180 days) Version to a Productive Version?
(Changing the Product Key)

Comment: That should be possible. Go to central administration > Upgrade and Migration > Convert farm license type and enter your product key.

Comment: "It should be possible" is the problem :-( Sure?

Comment: Are you seeing any errors when trying the steps above?

Comment: Try this link.it will work perfectly.. http://tokhin.blogspot.com/2017/06/sharepoint-trail-key-expired-activation.html

Answer (score 1):

For SharePoint 2013, their is problem, when download a trial version it will not give you option to select between Standard & enterprise( as it give for 2010), It simply download the Enterprise trial version.

Now if you want to upgrade from 2013 trial to 2013 standard then it will not gonna happen. You have to upgrade it to SP2013 ent.

But if you want to use Sp2013 Standard then You will have to set up a new farm with the Standard licensed edition.

You might be able to deactivate all enterprise features and then move your content database. (untested, not officially supported) The clean way would be to move your content manually.

How insert the key check this http://www.superedge.net/2014/07/upgrading-sharepoint-2013-trial.html